# How can I install the package iftop?

Tags: software-installation

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and it's not updating when I try. I changed may server address for Ubuntu and DNS but it's still not working. I'm trying to install iotop but it doesn't. I have already changed my Ubuntu server location and changed DNS to Google's default server. I have already installed Zental correctly, but iotop doesn't appear, how can I install it?

Here the error log:

```
 root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0 InRelease                                                                                                 
Err http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0 Release.gpg                                                                                               
  Unable to connect to archive.zentyal.org:http:
Ign http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0 Release                                                                                                   
Ign http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/extra TranslationIndex                                                                                    
Ign http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/main TranslationIndex                                                                                     
Err http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
  Unable to connect to archive.zentyal.org:http:
Err http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/extra i386 Packages                                                                                       
  Unable to connect to archive.zentyal.org:http:
Err http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/extra Translation-en_US                                                                                   
  Unable to connect to archive.zentyal.org:http:
Err http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/extra Translation-en                                                                                      
  Unable to connect to archive.zentyal.org:http:
Err http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/main Translation-en_US                                                                                    
  Unable to connect to archive.zentyal.org:http:
Err http://archive.zentyal.org 3.0/main Translation-en                                                                                       
  Unable to connect to archive.zentyal.org:http:
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                                                                               
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                             
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                   
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                                            
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                      
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                                  
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                                                     
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                                                                                           
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                         
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                                                                                             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex                                                                            
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                                                                                     
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                                                                               
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US                                                                           
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                                                                              
  Unable to connect to archive.canonical.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                                                                           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                                                                                   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                                              
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                      
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                                              
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                                            
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                          
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                                                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex                              
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                     
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                                                 
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                                               
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                               
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                                           
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                                         
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                                             
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources                                         
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources                                       
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages                                       
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages                                   
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                                 
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                                           
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources                                       
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources                                     
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages                                     
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                                    
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                  
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                              
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                              
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_US                                     
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                                                           
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_US                                                                          
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                                                             
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_US                                                                      
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                                      
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US                             
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_US                                                                  
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                     
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en_US                                                                    
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                                                                       
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US                           
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                                 
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en_US                                                                
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en                                                                   
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
23% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14)] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.202)]
```

ping:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ping -c4 google.com
PING google.com (202.166.193.187) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 187.cache.google.com (202.166.193.187): icmp_req=1 ttl=62 time=3.08 ms
64 bytes from 187.cache.google.com (202.166.193.187): icmp_req=2 ttl=62 time=4.30 ms
64 bytes from 187.cache.google.com (202.166.193.187): icmp_req=3 ttl=62 time=3.50 ms
64 bytes from 187.cache.google.com (202.166.193.187): icmp_req=4 ttl=62 time=4.34 ms
```

error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install iftop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package iftop
```

Comment: Can you please show us the **full** error? You can [edit] your question by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath it. Or, you can copy the error to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give us the URL.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6055880/

Answer (score 8):

From your comment, it seems that you are trying to install `iftop`, but it's telling you it's not there.

`iftop` is in the Universe repository, so you need to enable it. Visit this question: [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) to enable it. When you enable it, first do `apt-get update`, then try `apt-get install iftop`.

---

The correct command to update your package list is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, the command to actually upgrade your Ubuntu (i.e. download and install the newer versions of packages) is:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

> See my answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/344363/52726 for a little bit more explanation on the difference between `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

The command to install packages (or "applications") is:

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

Where `<packagename>` is the name of the application. For example `skype`, `vlc`, and so on.

The command you ran, `apt-get install update` is telling Ubuntu to install a package called `update`, which doesn't exist.