# How to solve "Unable to locate package update" when doing sudo apt-get install update

Tags: apt

When I want to update packages it shows this error:

```
gopi@Gopi-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install update
[sudo] password for gopi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
```

Comment: because your command is wrong.. If you want to upgrade your system.. Run this command `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Exact duplicate of: [“Failed to fetch” while updating](http://askubuntu.com/q/339919/52726).

Comment: @Alaa I just can't understand how this question is duplicate of ["How can I install the package iftop?"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339919/how-can-i-install-the-package-iftop).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Look at the history of that iftop question. The user was asking the same exact thing at first: he couldn't run "sudo apt-get install update". So I answered that question, which is almost identical to your answer below. When I saw this question here, I marked it as an exact duplicate. But then that iftop question evolved and his problem was that he couldn't install `iftop`. I edited my answer there to include that information for him, but I didn't remove the original answer because I had marked this as a duplicate to it.

Comment: Why are you guys reopening this question? The answer to the question marked is almost the *same exact answer* as the one by Radu. My answer even includes `sudo apt-get install <package_name>`. The title of a question doesn't matter. If the answer to two questions is the same, regardless of the question, they should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Alaa please read the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/213575). I had to edit the question since the main question of OP was "How to install the iftop package" the install update issue is irrelevant for OP since it's just a mere confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `sudo apt-get install update`, the system will try to install a package called `update` which doesn't exists and because of this you get that error.

The correct command to resynchronize the package index files from their sources is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or:

```
sudo aptitude update
```

Now, if you want to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources, use `upgrade` instead `update`.

See also `man apt-get` and `man aptitude`.